# Is it possible to catch all rest requests on a single consumer and forward to actual rest web service using cxfrs?

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, cxfrs

Right not i can map a single consumer to single rest service as per below code:

Route configurations:

```
    <bean class="com.x.ws.integration.route.SampleRouteProcessor"
    id="sampleRouteProcessor" />
<camel:routeContext id="xyz">
    <camel:route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <camel:from
            uri="cxfrs:bean:getSampleHoliDay?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer" />
        <camel:setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>GET</constant>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
            <constant>application/json</constant>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:setHeader headerName="accept">
            <constant>application/json</constant>
        </camel:setHeader>

        <camel:to uri="cxfrs:bean:getSampleHoliDayClient" />
    </camel:route>
</camel:routeContext>
<cxf:rsServer id="getSampleHoliDay" loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
    serviceClass="com.nucleus.rest.consumer.RestConsumerImpl">

    <cxf:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </cxf:providers>
</cxf:rsServer>
<!--Create receipt REST service Producer service client -->
<cxf:rsClient id="getSampleHoliDayClient"
    address="http://10.*.*.*:*/sample-integration/rest/"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true">
    <cxf:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />

    </cxf:providers>
</cxf:rsClient>
```

Consumer at integration:

```
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
public interface RestConsumer 
{

    @GET
    @Path("/getSampleRequest")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<String, Object> getSampleResponse();
}
```

Now if i make @Path("/*") it won't work. I want to create a single RestConsumer which should be able to catch all rest requests and forward accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Use a standard jetty http-listener and then route requests to different handlers. You'll have to handle the REST actions and mapping yourself, or use the REST-DSL.

See the 'matchOnUriPrefix' setting of camel-jetty: http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html

REST DSL: http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html